# How to get addon from github

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to download an addon linked in a tutorial called UV squares but don't know how to get the file exactly from github. I think it's supposed to be free

Here's the link, kindly help: https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares

[image: The options I'm seeing]

Answer (score 2):

To do this, simply click on the green `Code` button on the main page of the project and select `Download ZIP` there.

If there are specific releases for a project, you can also find the ZIP files in the navigation on the right under **Releases**. This is rather recommended if you want to use tested releases.

But of course you also have the possibility to download directly via the command line program [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git).
This procedure is called *cloning* and using it is relatively simple.

To clone a repository, use the following command on the command line:

```
git clone <remote-repo>
```

In your specific case, this would be:

```
git clone https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares.git
```

If you want to clone a specific branch, you can do so by also specifying the name of the branch:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>
```

Comment: I feel so silly, thank you!!!