# Add-on what should I download?

Tags: modeling

When I download *Principal Baker* from GitHub and I put install in preferences, what am I suppose to add? Like every single file or certain ones?

[image]

Comment: Often add-ons are installed directly from the .zip file (without extracting it). Try selecting the whole .zip archive from _Preferences > Addons > Install_

Comment: I don't get it, when I select the whole thing and click add on it takes me into one of the files and then it I don't know if I am suppose to highlight or not. I also checked videos and I placed it into my desktop and when I tried doing it again it gave me the same thing. @Christopher Bennett

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260480/how-to-get-addon-from-github https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly

Answer (score 1):

For this particular addon, downloading a complete ZIP file can also be done. Refer the image below to see how you can download the ZIP file for the same.

[image: Go to the "Code" dropdown and click "Download ZIP"]

Save the ZIP file in your preferred location and install the zip in blender. Choose the ZIP file and click OK.

That did the job for me. Hope this helped you.

Comment: your first sentence is wrong. Of course you can also install add-ons if it is just the .py file. And also you can install add-ons by just moving them in the right folder. So you should delete or change your first sentence. Thx.

Comment: I have edited my answer. That was just a small mistake. I forgot. I am sorry, @24k Edgar. How about this, @Chris?

Comment: much better, thx! +1